# Xamarin Live Player Unable to Connect - Keeps resetting address

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-live-player

Using VS 2017 15.7.4
Connecting to Live Player, connects fine then immediately disconnects.  Read about the config file in \AppData\Roaming and noticed that the IP address of my phone keeps getting reset to 0s no matter how many times I pair with VS either with the QR code or manually.  Connection test in Live Player shows IP and says 'should be able to pair with Visual Studio'

Attempting connection to debug address: 0.0.0.0:37847.